# Cannot resolve method 'super(?,java.lang.String, com.android.volley.Response.Listener<java.lang.String>,null)'

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio

So, i have this problem that it looks that it doesn't resolve the method, this code is from a "response" class and it's used to insert data in a Hostinger database. The error message is: "Cannot resolve method 'super(?,java.lang.String, com.android.volley.Response.Listener,null)'" and "Cannot resolve symbol 'Method'"

```
package com.example.nikochan.instaticket;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CrearRequest extends CrearEvento {

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL ="http://instatickethome.xyz/Crea.php";
    private Map<String,String> params;

    public CrearRequest(String nombreevento, String fecha, String descripcion, String hora, String genero, int edad, String duracion, int precio, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null  );
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("nombreevento", nombreevento );
        params.put("descirpcion", descripcion );
        params.put("hora", hora );
        params.put("genero", genero );
        params.put("edad", edad + "");
        params.put("duracion", duracion );
        params.put("precio", precio + "");

    }

    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to import the Method class.

Comment: could you post dependency section in your build.gradle file

Answer (score 1):

You could import Method class or modify code like below:

```
super(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
```

Comment: I already done that, but the problem in "super" method still apears...
I also put this in the "CrearEvento" class and seems to solve the problem, it's ok??: public CrearEvento(int post, String registerRequestUrl, Response.Listener<String> listener, Object o) {
    }